# FIWARE - Token API Orion Context Broker

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have in my server a Orion Context Broker (https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion) but i need to add some restrictions to my "consumers" when they use the endpoint(s) e.g(http://myhost:1026/v2/entities). Is possible configure the local/personal Broker with token like https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/1.11.0/quick_start_guide/index.html#orion-context-broker-quick-start-guide ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Orion Context Broker does not offer roles and permissions directly.
To add roles and permissions to restrict an endpoint, you will need to use a **PEP Proxy** - which security mechanism you use to do this is up to you.

There are several OAuth2-based security components found within the [FIWARE Catalogue](https://github.com/FIWARE/catalogue/blob/master/security/README.md), alternatively you could another open source PEP Proxy such as [steelskin](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin) which integrates nicely with either [Keyrock](https://fiware-idm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [Keystone](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-pep-steelskin/blob/master/keystoneInstallation.md)